# EXCEL: Search for a value in a range and return its adjacent value in a particular column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

this is my sample data

```
1   0   11  12  A
2   9   13  14  B
3   8   15  16  C
4   7   17  20  D
5   6   18  19  E
```

I need a  excel formula which returns B when i input 14 or 13 or 9 or 2 similarly it should return me A if i input 1 or 0 or 11 or 12.

Can anyone please help me

I tried with INDEX and match functions like

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$E$5,MATCH(G1,IF(($B$1:$D$5=G1)+($A$1:$A$5=G1), $B$1:$D$5),0)),"Not Found")
```

My input was 12. but its giving me Value not found , though the value is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative approach using <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd>, <kbd>MAX( )</kbd> & <kbd>ROW( )</kbd>

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=INDEX($E$1:$E$5,MAX(--(H1=A1:D5)*(ROW(A1:D5))))
```

---

**Caveat:** Since you have tagged as `Excel-2007` don't forget to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

Answer (score 2):

Excel-2007? Really? If so, then try:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
{=INDEX(E1:E5,MATCH(1,MMULT(N(A1:D5=G1),{1;1;1;1}),0))}
```

If dynamic arrays are available:

```
=CONCAT(REPT(E1:E5,A1:D5=G1))
```